# Save an *.rda file as a data.frame

Tags: r, rda

This question has been asked several times, but I haven't found a solution.  I have an rda R file (df) that I want to save as a non binary file (such as txt or csv) so I can use it in a text editor program...

Is there a way to do this?

Right now using `write.csv(df, file=out.csv)` or even, `saveRDS(df, file=out.rds)` gives me an empty file.

What am I missing here....

EDIT: I'm working with an rda file not an rds file as stated originally

Comment: write.csv is the way to do this, so without more information, it's going to be very difficult for us to help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/210673 for information on how to improve your question so we can better help.

Comment: Without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) it is a bit hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: Actually - there is a typo in my question... I'm working with an rda file... not an rds.

Comment: The input file is irrelevant once you've loaded it into R, so what is `df`? If it's a data.frame, the first option (with quotes on the path) should work, e.g. `write.csv(mtcars, '~/Desktop/mtcars.csv')`.

Comment: Thats just to refer to my data... it is an object right now with a "character" class.  I want to save into a data frame so I can use it with other programs.  It isn't one now. And write.csv does not work, even following your suggestions with quotes.

Comment: @Jaap: I don't have any reproducible data.  As this has been saved by someone else.  I'm trying to load it and save it as a dataframe, that is all.

Answer (score 0):

An `RDA` file is, by definition, a file that has been persisted to disk and is not to be confused with a variable that is in memory (or your workspace). To read in `.RDA` files you use `load(file = "<path>")`. If you have the path of your `.RDA` file you can use this:

```
load(file = "<your path>/<your filename>.RDA")
write.csv(<var name>, file="out.csv")
```

Make sense?

Comment: Yeah - this makes sense.  And I thought this would be this simple... but it gives me the error: unused argument (path="<your path>/<your filename>.RDA")

Comment: oh, right sorry that was from the `.rds` function. I'm updating.

Comment: `load(file = "/data/myfile.rda")` remember this always picks up the file from the current working directory. If you need to know what that is use `getwd()` and set it using `setwd()`.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you have an object of class `character`, i.e. a vector of strings,
you can use `cat` to write it to a file.

```
df <- LETTERS # = c("A", "B", ..., "Z")
cat(df, file = "my/path/to/data.txt", sep = "\n", append = FALSE)
```

Now the file will have the contents

```
A
B
C
...
Z
```